# Imprimir una frase limitando a 41 letras o numeros, Python

Tags: python, condiciones

Buen día estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con este pequeño codigo, No encuentro la forma de como hacer que funcione.

Busco imprimir de un titulo un máximo de 41 letras o números(no signos o espacios).

Es decir: Si el titulo lleva 42 palabras, Solo imprimirá 41 y si llevan menos o igual 41 lo imprimirá como tal. Pero excluyen do "Episodio 2"

Ejemplo:

Titulo: `"IS: Infinite Stratos 2 - Episodio 2"`  #Tiene 27 caracteres excluyendo el `:`,`-` y espacios
Entonces lo imprimirá como tal.

Pero si el titulo fuera asi:

Titulo:  `"IS: Infinite Stratos 2 segunda temporada - Episodio 2"` #Tiene `43` caracteres excluyente el `:`,`-` y espacios
, Entonces busco que el código excluyen el `- Episodio 2` y limite el  `"IS: Infinite Stratos 2 segunda temporada` y lo limite hasta la letra en donde las dos partes sumen un máximo de `41`.

Esto es lo que eh estado intentando:

```
import re
Titulo = "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 Segunda Temporada - Episodio 2"
nm = re.sub(r'[^\d.a-zA-Z ]','',re.sub(",", ".", Titulo)) #Explcuyo los signos y espacios para contar solo letras y números

if len(nm) << 41: #Si el titulo sin signos y espacios es menos a 41, lo imprime como tal
   print(Titulo)
else: 
   print()   #Y aqui el problema, Como limitar El titulo a 41 caracteres excluyendo el `- Episodio 2`(cabe recalcar que el numero 2 puedes variar a 20 o 200)
```

En ese ejemplo El titulo cuenta `43` Entonces debería imprimir `IS: Infinite Stratos 2 segunda tempora - Episodio 2` y de esa forma contar `41`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte del problema es como contar la longitud del texto de acuerdo a tus reglas (solo letras y digitos). Eso lo solucionamos con una función apropiada:

```
def largo(palabra):
    return len([letradig for letradig in palabra if letradig.isalnum()])
```

Esta función crea una lista con las letras alfanumericas y retorna su largo, o sea, el número de caracteres de interés.

Tenemos la función `corta41` para cortar títulos a 41 caracteres.

Usaremos `find()` para detectar la presencia de un episodio. La función `find` retorna -1 si el texto no se encuentra.

Si existe " - Episodio", entonces la palabra se corta en dos y se procede a botar un caracter de la primera parte hasta reducir el largo total a 41 o hasta que se agote la primera parte.

Finalmente, se recorta cualquier exceso que haya quedado del proceso anterior.

```
def corta41(palabra):
    if largo(palabra) > 41:
        idx = palabra.find(" - Episodio")
        if idx > 0:
            #   Separar en dos el titulo
            izq = palabra[:idx] 
            der = palabra[idx:] 
            restante = 41 - largo(der) # Espacio disponible.
            if restante > 0:
                # Hay espacio, recortar la izuierda
                while izq and largo(izq) > restante:
                    izq = izq[:-1]
                palabra = izq + der
            else:
                # No hay espacio, asignarlo todo a la derecha
                palabra = izq
        # Finalmente, asegurarse de respetar largo maximo        
        while largo(palabra) > 41:
            palabra = palabra[:-1]

    return palabra
```

**Comprobación**

```
   tests = [
    "a b",
    "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 - Episodio 2",
    "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 segunda temporada - Episodio 2",
    "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 [X:::Y] segunda temporada - Episodio 2",
    "Watashi-Nōryoku-wa-Heikinchi-    dddddddddd  de-tte-Itta-yo-ne! - Episodio-3",
    "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901",
    "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012",
    "uno - Episodio 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123 - no es un episodio",
    "-uno",
    " - dos"
    ]


for test in tests:
    word = corta41(test)
    print(largo(word), word)
```

produce

```
2 a b
27 IS: Infinite Stratos 2 - Episodio 2
41 IS: Infinite Stratos 2 segunda tempora - Episodio 2
41 IS: Infinite Stratos 2 [X:::Y] segunda tempo - Episodio 2
41 Watashi-Nōryoku-wa-Heikinchi-    ddddddd - Episodio-3
41 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901
41 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901
3 uno
41 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901
3 -uno
3  - dos
```

Comment: Sera posible separar tambien los ultimos 3 digitos de la variable izq. Ejemplo: `soy un titulo largo xvc - episodio 2` a `soy un titulo la xvc - episodio 2`. los ultimos 3 digitos se mantienen y lo demas se resta. Y suman 41.

Comment: lo logre, en vez de 3 digitos use la ultima palabra con un una nueva variable `izk = palabra[:idx].rsplit(' ',1)[1]` y sumandolo al `largo(izq) + largo(izk)` y agregandolo al `palabra = izq +" "+izk + der`. Por si a alguien le sirve!.

Answer (score 3):

Para limitar la cantidad de caracteres a un numero puedes usar la sintáxis de
rebanado de cadenas.  La ventaja es que deja la cadena como está si no pasa de
ese número de caracteres. Por ejemplo:

```
titulo = "Watashi, Nōryoku wa Heikinchi de tte Itta yo ne! - Episodio 2"

cortado = titulo[:41]

assert(len(cortado) <= 41) # la longitud es menor o igual a 41
```

Pero eso no haría que quede el número de episodio en el título, así que se
podría:

1. Separar el episodio del nombre de la serie con `str.rsplit` usando `" - "`
   como separador.
2. Cortar el nombre de la serie teniendo en cuenta la longitud del separador y
   el episodio.
3. Concatenar el nombre de la serie cortado, con el separador y el episodio.

Algo así:

```
def limitar_titulo(titulo, limite):
    separador = " - "

    nombre_serie, episodio = titulo.rsplit(separador, 1)

    serie_cortada = nombre_serie[:limite - len(separador) - len(episodio)]

    return serie_cortada + separador + episodio

titulo = "Watashi, Nōryoku wa Heikinchi de tte Itta yo ne! - Episodio 3"

cortado = limitar_titulo(titulo, 41)

assert(cortado == "Watashi, Nōryoku wa Heikinch - Episodio 3")
assert(len(cortado) <= 41)
```

Comment: No es exactamente exacto lo que buscaba, pero me sirve jaja gracias!

Comment: Disculpa como podria hacer si el titulo es de esta forma `Watashi-Nōryoku-wa-Heikinchi-de-tte-Itta-yo-ne!-Episodio-3`

Comment: @RicharlyxD sería un hack feo pero tal vez puedas usar `"-Episodio-"` como separador en vez de `" - "`.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que después de "- Episodio" viene algún número, que puede tener más de un dígito, así que voy a hacer algo más general:

1. Busco el reverso de este, en el reverso del título (o sea, busco la primera ocurrencia de "oidosipE - "), y lo guardo en **final**.
2. Guardo en **posible** la suma del largo de "- Episodio" con **final**.
3. En **corte** guardo el mínimo de (el largo del título - **posible**, y la cantidad de caracteres que quieres mantener (**caracteres**))
4. Finalmente, junto titulo hasta corte, con episodio, y el titulo desde final ([-final:])

Aquí el código

```
def cortar(titulo, episodio, caracteres):
  final = titulo[::-1].find(episodio[::-1]) # Paso 1
  posible = len(episodio) + final # Paso 2
  #titulo = titulo.replace(":","") # OPCIONAL, reemplaza lo que necesites (simbolos, espacios, etc por string vacio)
  corte = min(len(titulo) - posible, caracteres) # Paso 3
  resultado = (titulo[:corte] + episodio + titulo[-final:]) # Paso 4
  return resultado

titulo = "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 Segunda Temporada - Episodio 2"
episodio = "- Episodio"
print(cortar(titulo, episodio, 10))
IS: Infini- Episodio 2

titulo = "IS: Infinite Stratos 2 Segunda Temporada - Episodio 1234"
print(cortar(titulo, episodio, 10))
IS: Infini- Episodio 1234
```